What does "closed" have to do with it

Giant in scale are those who dare to follow me
It would be a stretch if we should ever meet
Who I am inside to figure out is easy
Knowing me skin-deep is quite a nasty feat

Who am I? Bonus points if you actually do know me skin-deep.
